# При запуске nvim в git bash ничего не происходит

Tags: vim, git-bash

Хотел поставить neovim в git bash, но при попытке его открыть открывается пустое окно и ничего не просходит[image: Запуск nvim]

открывается это и на этом всё. Просто все команды стёрлись и запустилось это, у меня получилось только завершить процесс сочетанием Ctrl+C. Если файл nvim.exe запустить отдельно, то всё работает нормально, он открывается в каком-то окне и работает. Через bash можно запустить только nvim-qt, но опять же, он открывается в отдельном окне, в отличие от обычного запуска vim.

Может быть с установкой neovim я что-то сделал не так? Скачал архив https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.4.4 и перенёс содержимое папки bin и share в папки гита /usr/bin и /usr/share соответственно. Настройки vim'а перенёс в nvim, но это не помогло. Пытался провернуть такое и с x64 версией, и с x32, ничего не изменилось.

При попытке коммита выскакивает следующее сообщение:
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: There was a problem with the editor 'nvim'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Сразу говорит, что проблема с nvim. После установки редактора nvim-qt и попытке коммита вылазит окно Neovim с надписью, что программа крашнулась
[image: Коммит через nvim-qt]

В общем не знаю, что делать. Может надо было по другому всё это дело провернуть?

Comment: вот почему виндузятники вечно скачивают бинарники непонятно откуда и спокойно ставят их себе на комп? Попробуйте его сами скомпилировать и поставить - скорее всего у вас какой-нить pdcurses не стоит или что-то типа того

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch тут вопрос про использование neovim и git-bash. Если даже не перемещать bin'ы и share'ы куда-то, а просто указать
git config --global core.editor "путь до nvim.exe"
ничего не изменится, будет такая же шляпа.
Или запустить nvim указав к нему путь, тоже ничего не меняется.

Comment: тобишь сам по себе neovim работает? Хм, видимо у вас проблема в путях к либам

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch пока копался, нашёл кое-что интересное. Если запустить bash.exe или sh.exe из директории Git/bin, то nvim прекрасно работает. Видимо из-за того, что nvim в данном случае запускается из терминала винды, а git-bash использует эмулятор MinTYY, в котором почему-то nvim не работает. Теперь интересно, можно-ли заставить MinTYY запустить нормально nvim или придётся использовать терминал винды?

Comment: По поводу vim, который работает и там и там - вероятно это разные сборки vim

Comment: [GH Issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6751)

Comment: @vp_arth Установил экспериментальную версию git, теперь neovim работает. Решение было так близко, оказывается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы корректо использовать neovim в качестве редактора в git и консоли, надо в процессе установки в качестве терминала выбрать терминал винды, а не MinTTY, либо ставить Linux и пользоваться гитом из родного терминала. ***Новое решение: установить экспериментальную версию гита***

***Лично я другого решения не нашёл, вы можете покапаться в этом вопросе поглубже, например на гитхабе с neovim в вопросах, на англоязычном stackoverflow и т.д.***